# OpenAPI : change request body schema

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a class

```java
public abstract class Transfer<ID_TYPE> {

    protected ID_TYPE id;
    protected BigDecimal amount;
    protected String text;
    protected Debitor debit;
    protected Creditor credit;
    
}
```

```java
public class Debitor  {

    private Reference<String, String> number;
    private Integer property;
    
}
```

```java
public class Reference<T, U> {

    T reference;
    U value;
}
```

I have a `RestController` with `POST`

```java
    public ResponseEntity<Transfer> post(@RequestBody Transfer transfer,
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
   // do something
}
```

What I need to do, is to override the schema of my requestbody in the open api definition to hides some fields (only for post method)

```java
{
   debit: {
     number: {
        reference: 'value' // Reference.value is hidden
      }
   }
}
```

I cannot change the signature of my POST endpoint and cannot a create DTO to only expose required fields.

What I tried to do so far :

1. Annotate my fields with `@Schema` that should not be displayed in swagger with a READ ONLY access mode
   => This solution is not good because it number.reference.value might be mandatory for other post method.
2. Try to add @RequestBody

```java
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = {

            @Content(schema = @Schema(name = "number", type = "integer", required = true)) })
```

But when I use this annotation, the property' name is not displayed
and I don't know how to handle nested properties.

Is there a way to do that ?
Can we create a custom open api yaml file that would override the default one only on few endpoints ?

Thanks for your help